# extjs using up and down methods

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to use `up` and `down` to call rather than `Ext.getCmp` but I'm not quite understanding it. I have this code

```
listeners: {
    'change': function(field, selectedValue) {
        // Ext.getCmp('wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);
        this.up('form').down('#wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);
    }
}
```

inside this larger code

```
Ext.define('ryan', {
    constructor: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            bodyStyle: {"background-color":"green"},
            name: 'mypanel',
            title: 'Animal sanctuary, one animal per location  ',
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            test: 'mycat',
            style: 'background-color: #Fdd;',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                itemId: 'button1',
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'click the button',
                handler: function() {
                    alert('(<^_^>)');
                }
            },{
                itemId: 'wildAnimal',
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'animal:',
                name: 'myanimal'
            },{
                itemId: 'myCombo',
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'choose your animal',
                store: animals,
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                listeners: {
                    'change': function(field, selectedValue) {
                        // Ext.getCmp('wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);
                        this.up('form').down('#wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});

var animals = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['itemId', 'name'],
    data: [{
        "itemId": 'mycat',
        "name": "mycat"
    },{
        "itemId" : 'mydog', 
        "name": "mydog"
    },{
        'itemId' : 'sbBarGirls', 
        "name": "BarGirls-when-drunk"
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var a = Ext.create('ryan');
    var b = Ext.create('ryan');
});
```

What I'm confused on is why I need the hashtag in `wildAnimal` to get this working. Also when I switch `Ext.form.Panel` to `widget.window` the listeners code stops working. My code creates a window but I can't pass the value of the combobox like I can when it's a form panel. As I understand it `up` is used to find stuff from the parent class. When using a `widget.window` do I call `this.up(widget)`? I can't get that to work. Also I'm very new to Ext JS so many things may go over my head >__<.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `up` and `down` methods are used to traverse the component tree.

When using `up` and `down` with selectors, the default selector checks the xtype of the component. So `up('form')` means "keep going up the component tree until you find a form." The `#wildAnimal` selector means "keep going up until you find the component where id == 'wildAnimal'". If you use `up()` with no selectors, it returns the parent container.

If you decide to use `Ext.window.Window` instead of `Ext.form.Panel` you would need to change all occurrences of `up('form')` with `up('window')`. Otherwise, if you know that "myCombo" and "wildAnimal" are sibling components you can just use `up().down('#wildAnimal')` and it will work after changing the type of parent container.

Comment: do i always need to have the hash tag ?? i've seen examples with no hastag

Comment: Only if you want to select on `id` or `itemId`. Other methods like `Ext.getCmp` assume the input string is an ID and do not require the hashtag.

Answer (score 5):

The symantics of up and down methods follow the [**ComponentQuery**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) class.  Highly recommend you read the API docs on this. And also see below for getting started with ExtJS.

Good luck!

---

I am just going to leave this here for you.

This is a getting started list of resources that I put together for my colleagues:
Obviously links are to ExtJS4.1 but feel free to grab the same for the latest version.

API :
  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/

Examples : 
       http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/

Guides : 
    http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide

Resources:

Sencha Forum : 
     http://www.sencha.com/forum/

StackOverflow : 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs

Tools:

Firebug Plugin (Illuminations for Developers)

http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/

How To Get Started

```
1. Scroll through the Examples to get ideas of what you want to build.
2. Read through these Guides :
    ○ Getting Started
    ○ Class System
    ○ MVC
    ○ Layouts
    ○ Components
    ○ Data Package
```

Once you are familiar with these concepts decide which components you will use and take a deeper look at the specific guides under the Components section. I would also advise reading through the App Architecture tutorials.